# Can not retrieve session data in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

When I try to retrieve session data in spring boot it always gives me a null value. Session attribute data is stored in the database as a BLOB file. You can see the Session attribute table in the photo below.

[This is a photo of SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE table in mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbHU.png)

This is the code I use to store session data

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody LoginModel loginModel, HttpServletRequest request) {
List<String> messages = (List<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("IS_LOGGED_IN");
            if (messages == null) {
                messages = new ArrayList<>();
                request.getSession().setAttribute("IS_LOGGED_IN", messages);
            }
            messages.add("hellooooo");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("IS_LOGGED_IN", messages);
}
```

This is the code I use to retrieve session data.

```
@GetMapping("/check")
    public void  process(HttpSession session) {

        List<String> messages = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("IS_LOGGED_IN");
        System.out.println(messages);
    }
```

This is the code I use in the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout.seconds=900
server.port=9092
```

[This is a photo of SPRING_SESSION table in mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmr3j.png)

Comment: (1) Don't reinvent authentication. (2) Inject `HttpSession` as a controller parameter instead of `HttpServletRequest`. (3) Consider `@SessionAttribute` where appropriate.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-I tried your answer. but it give me null value for the session data.

Comment: I create a sample project like your code  and all things work correct

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani can you retrieve session data from the database?

Comment: Check this repository https://github.com/azizkhani/spring-session-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

option 1 -
use this HttpSession httpSession as an argument to get and set properties.

Second, if you are using Springboot + security the other option available for checking any login related is via

```
public String login(Principal principal)
```

It will give you null if no logged in user and will provide you a login id by-

```
principal.getName();
```

and using the Model model object for transferring data.

```
model.addAttribute("data", data);
```